# How to get server roles and database roles in a same query/script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get all database roles and server roles in the same query/script? if so then how can it be achieved?

The First query gives all the server roles and the second query gives following all the database roles, I can join the two queries with 'Union All' but the issue with the second query is it doesn't show any database Name which I need.

```
select @@SERVERNAME AS 'ServerName',
       logins.default_database_name AS DatabaseSchemaName,
       logins.name As LoginName,
       logins.type As Type,
    logins.type_desc As Type_Desc,
       sr.[name] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS 'Roles&Permissions'                 
from  sys.server_principals logins 
inner join sys.server_role_members srm on logins.principal_id = srm. member_principal_id
Inner join sys.server_principals sr ON role_principal_id = sr.principal_id 
where logins.is_fixed_role <>1


SELECT @@SERVERNAME as 'Server Name',
       logins.default_schema_name AS SchemaName,
       logins.name AS Name,
    logins.type As Type,
    logins.type_desc AS Type_Desc,
       db.[name] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS 'Roles&Permissions'                 
FROM  sys.database_principals logins 
inner join sys.database_role_members drm on logins.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
Inner join sys.database_principals db ON role_principal_id = db.principal_id
```

The end goal is to get all the databases in the SQL server instance with the roles(e.g db_owner). This will be stored in a temp table from where I can export it to excel. So when the above queries didn't work, I wrote another one after doing some reading and online searching. In the following query, I am getting the database roles along with the respective database so that issue is resolved but I want server roles as well but don't know how to add those in this query.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME,    
        @sql VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE(DatabaseName VARCHAR(100), ServerName VARCHAR(100), Name VARCHAR(100), TypeDesc Varchar(100), DatabaseRole VARCHAR(100) )
DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR 
     FOR SELECT Name FROM sys.databases
OPEN databaseCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM databaseCursor INTO @DatabaseName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql ='SELECT ''' + @DatabaseName + ''' AS [Database],
                      ''' +@@SERVERNAME +  '''AS [Server Name],
                      logins.name Name,
                      logins.type_desc TypeDesc, 
                      roles.name RoleName
               FROM '+@databaseName+'.sys.database_role_members rm
               INNER JOIN '+@databaseName +'.sys.database_principals roles ON rm.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
               INNER JOIN '+@databaseName+'.sys.database_principals logins ON rm.member_principal_id = logins.principal_id'
    INSERT INTO @ResultTable EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM databaseCursor INTO @databaseName
END
CLOSE databaseCursor 
DEALLOCATE databaseCursor 
SELECT * FROM @ResultTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If figuring out members with Server login permissions and also Database Roles can fulfil your requirement, then we may use [sys.database_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT ROL.name AS Role_Name 
      ,MEM.name AS Member_Name 
      ,MEM.type_desc AS Member_Type 
      ,MEM.default_schema_name AS DefaultSchema 
      ,SP.name AS ServerLogin 
FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM 
     INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS ROL 
         ON DRM.role_principal_id = ROL.principal_id 
     INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS MEM 
         ON DRM.member_principal_id = MEM.principal_id 
     INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS SP 
         ON MEM.[sid] = SP.[sid] 
ORDER BY Role_Name 
        ,Member_Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but if you look at my last script you can see I am declaring a table and I am getting all the column I need, I just need help how to modify it in a way that it gives me server roles as well.